# На inline кнопке в Telegram висит иконка ожидания

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет, писал бота на node-telegram-bot-api. Добавил кнопку, нажал на нее, она отработала и вернула результат, но даже после результата на ней висит иконка ожидания. В чем может быть проблема?

```
const TelegramBotApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
require('dotenv').config()

const bot = new TelegramBotApi(process.env.TOKEN, { polling: true })

const options = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{text: 'Tap', callback_data: 'tap'}]
        ]
    })
}

bot.onText(/\/start/, async (msg) => {
    return bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hi', options)
})

bot.on('callback_query', async (msg) =>{
    return bot.sendMessage(msg.message.chat.id, 'Tapped')
})
```

[image: Скрин результата]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно ответить на этот колбек..

```js
bot.on('callback_query', msg => {
  bot.answerCallbackQuery(msg.id).then(() => {
    if (msg.data == 'tap') {
      bot.sendMessage(msg.message.chat.id, 'Tapped');
    }
  });
})
```